# how to print task name using taskId in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, table-relationships

I am developing project management app using laravel 5.2 and in my application user can create project and one project have many tasks and one task have many sub tasks. this is my relationship with each models

project Model

```
public function tasks(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}
```

Task Model

```
public function subtasks(){
        return $this->hasMany(Subtask::class);
    }
```

Subtask Model

```
 public function task(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }
```

this is my subtask input form in subtasks/form.blade.php

Add Sub Task

```
 <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('subtasks.form', ['projectId'=> $projectId, 'taskId'=>$taskId])}}">
     <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
     <input type="text" name="task_name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{ old('task_name') ?: '' }}">
     @if ($errors->has('task_name'))
         <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('task_name') }}</span>
     @endif
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Create Task</button>
     </div>
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
 </form>
```

route

```
Route::get('projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask', function ($projectId, $taskId) {

    return view('subtasks/form',['projectId'=>$projectId,'taskId'=>$taskId]);
});
```

in my form file I can print $projectId and $ taskId as well but now I need print project_name and task_name regarding to ids how can I do this?

**updated question**
please see my subtask store methods

```
public function store(Request $request,$projectId,$taskId)
    {
        $subtask = new Subtask;
        $subtask->subtask_name = $request->input('task_name');
        $subtask->task_id = $taskId;
        $subtask->project_id = $projectId;

        $subtask->save();
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like so (Q&D solution):

```
Route::get('projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask', function ($projectId, $taskId) {
    $project = \App\ProjectModel::find($projectId);
    $task = \App\TaskModel::find(taskId);
    return view('subtasks/form',['project'=>$project,'task'=>$task]);
});
```

Note: In your form action, you will need to update the following :

```
['projectId'=> $projectId, 'taskId'=>$taskId]
```

By :

```
['projectId'=> $project->id, 'taskId'=>$task->id]
```

Comment: please see my updated question how to change my subtask store method according to this new change

Comment: The code I gave you didn't changed anything. It just allows you to acces the other properties of your objects in your view. And in your update method, you still have your `$projectId` and `$taskId` variables. what is the error ?

Comment: Ow, see my edited answer, you need to provide your model name for project and task (with the FQN if you didn't `use` it).

Comment: now got this error **routes.php line 120: Class 'App\ProjectModel' not found**

Comment: Man, you have to use YOUR model names, not mine... I don't know how you named your models...

Comment: please can you explain what is **Q&D solution** I am new to Laravel and Programming

Comment: Quick and dirty, you'd better refactor that into a controller method for example.